# Why Coroutine is behaving strangely in returning results?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, kotlin, coroutine

I have two methods say A and B , both are returning results from Coroutine Scope and both are implemented the same way  but one is working fine and other one is giving exception. Why they are behaving strangely? Here is my code of **A** method

```
fun addCartToFirebase(itemId: String,cart: Basket) : Pair<String,Int>?{
    var pair:Pair<String,Int>? = null
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        databaseReference.child("Cart").child("Anonymous").child(itemId).setValue(cart).addOnSuccessListener {
                pair = Pair("result",1)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                    pair = Pair("result",0)
             }
    }
    return pair
}
```

Method **A** is working fine but Method B is not working.Here is my code of **B**

```
fun submitFinalCart(cartData : HashMap<String,List<String>>) : Pair<String,Int>{
    var pair:Pair<String,Int>? = null
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            databaseReference.child("FinalCart").push().setValue(cartData).addOnSuccessListener {
               pair = Pair("result",1)
              }.addOnFailureListener {
                pair = Pair("result",0)
            }
       }
    return pair!!
}
```

Why is it so. How should i fix it?

Edited

My **ViewModel** class code

```
fun setCart(itemId : String, cart: Basket) : Pair<String,Int>?{
    return firebaseNetwork.addCartToFirebase(itemId,cart)
}
```

My **Fragment** class code

```
binding.addToCart.setOnClickListener {
        val cart = Basket()
        cart.itemsId = itemId
        cart.itemWeight =binding.counter.text.toString()
        val pair = selectedItemViewModel.setCart(binding.category?.id!!,cart)
        Log.d("pair value",pair?.second?.toString()!!)
        if(pair.second == 0){
            showShortToast("Failed")
        }
        else{
            showShortToast("Success")
            binding.cartIndicator.visibility =View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should make the function suspend and use `withContext(IO)` instead, or use async, and return the deferred that you can do await on later.

Comment: but at some stage I have to call that method from suspend function. But the thing remains the same as i can't able to return value from suspend function.

Comment: `launch` is not intended for retruning a value. It for launching coroutine and forget about it. And for listener functions you can use the `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine` instead

Comment: @AnimeshSahu okay but how can i return response to the function where i started Coroutine when the listener returns success and go to next activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the method `addCartToFirebase` returns `null`. The method `submitFinalCart` would like to do the same but `!!` doesn't allow it. You have to wait until your coroutines will be finished or return `Deferred<Pair<String,Int>>`

You can use for example `suspendCoroutine` to acquire result from callback like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun submitFinalCart(cartData: HashMap<String, List<String>>): Pair<String, Int> =
    withContext(IO) {
        suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            databaseReference.child("FinalCart").push().setValue(cartData).addOnSuccessListener {
                continuation.resume(Pair("result", 1))
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                continuation.resume(Pair("result", 0))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No its not returning null but a result containing  1 as a value

Comment: yes you were true , they both actually returning null. So now how can i return response to the function from Coroutine when the listener return the result.

Comment: okay , i checked your solution but at some stage i'll call this method again from Coroutine  scope so how can i move to next activity after obtaining result. Things will remain the same as the main thread will not know whether the background thread has sent the result so that it can go to next activity..

Comment: When this function is asynchronous i.e. Expects a listener, you don't need to go on IO thread it won't block :) a suspendCoroutine will do the job.

Comment: @Mattwalk can't you do `launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate){/* change activity*/}` inside coroutine.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu what does it do ? i don't know about it ..and where should i place it ?

Comment: @Mattwalk could you attach the code where you start a new activity and handle the result of `submitFinalCart`

Comment: idk why you are switching threads, listener thing is already asynchronous and does not block.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu i know that too .. but here i wanted to check how is it possible with Coroutine, as later i am gonna use Retrofit so i wanted to get some work around with coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do the impossible. You want to return from a suspending call without suspending your function.

Just make the function suspending.

```kotlin
suspend fun addCartToFirebase(itemId: String, cart: Basket): Boolean =
    suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        databaseReference.child("Cart").child("Anonymous").child(itemId).setValue(cart).addOnSuccessListener {
            cont.resume(true)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            cont.resume(false)
        }
    }

suspend fun setCart(itemId: String, cart: Basket): Boolean =
    firebaseNetwork.addCartToFirebase(itemId,cart)

// Set your listener
binding.addToCart.setOnClickListener {
    val cart = Basket()
    cart.itemsId = itemId
    cart.itemWeight =binding.counter.text.toString()

    viewModelOwner.viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = selectedItemViewModel.setCart(binding.category?.id!!, cart)
        Log.d("result", result)

        if(result) {
            showShortToast("Success")
            binding.cartIndicator.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            // Start the activity here
        } else showShortToast("Failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, viewModel is actually launching a Coroutine ? i didn't know that.. btw its working  thanks..